# "Require all granted" in Apache VirtualHost config but still "You don't have permission to access /test on this server" (RewriteRule fails)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, virtualhost, apache2.4

Here is the full content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` Apache 2.4 config file on Debian:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 203.0.113.0
  DocumentRoot /home/www/203.0.113.0
  <Directory "/">
    Require all granted   # as required with Apache 2.4
  </Directory>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/test(.*)$ /index.html [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

- `a2enmod rewrite` has been executed and thus `mod_rewrite` is enabled (confirmed by `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` that shows `rewrite_module (shared)`)
- accessing `http://203.0.113.0/` from browser works, and displays succesfully the file `/home/www/203.0.113.0/index.html`
- `service apache2 restart` has already been executed

**Question: why does accessing `http://203.0.113.0/test` show:**

> **Forbidden**
>   **You don't have permission to access /test on this server.**
>   Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at ... Port 80

Comment: You mention that accessing `http://203.0.113.0:1234` works.  What about `http://localhost:1234`?  You are proxying to `http://localhost:1234`, test that one.  Could it be that you need to proxy to `http://203.0.113.0:1234` instead?

Comment: @Nic3500 Same error with the latter, even same error with `RewriteRule ^/test(.*)$ / [P,L]`, strangely!

Comment: @Nic3500 See the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

gave the solution:

> AH00669: attempt to make remote request from mod_rewrite without proxy enabled

So

```
a2enmod rewrite proxy proxy_http
```

solved the problem.